# Drupal 8 get value of a custom field that has multiple value

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-8

I'm developing a site with Drupal 8. I made a custom content type, with a lot of fields; in particular I have a field called "field_categoria_del_libro_presen" that is linked to a taxonomy term. It's possible to specify more than one value. I used kint() to obtain the structure of the node. Here:
field_categoria_del_libro_presen
→array(2) 
    target_id

## 1

"1"

## 2

"4"

I attached the screenshot too.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K6OD.jpg)
How can I get the value "1" and "4" that represent the terms of my taxonomy?
Thank you so much in advance.
Regards.
Valentina

ANOTHER QUESTION UNSOLVED:
how can I get the length of the array?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. So I answer my question.
{{ node.field_categoria_del_libro_presen.0.target_id}}
{{ node.field_categoria_del_libro_presen.1.target_id}}

Answer (score 0):

According to your self provided answer I guess you're talking about how to get the value in a twig template. Well generally speaking if you want to get the length of an array you can use the "length" filter. It looks like this:

```
{{ someArray|length }}
```

And regarding your original question, if the number of selected values varies and you want to display them all I would suggest using a for loop, it looks like this:

```
{% for arrayElement in someArray %}
    {{ arrayElement.someKey }}
{% endfor %}
```

For more information look here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html

and here:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/length.html